# Not able to run an Excel Macro loop throughout the workbook due to overflow error

Tags: vba, excel, loops, integer-overflow

I have 7 sheets with over 70,000 entries; which I am summing per unique attribute in a separate column on each sheet.

While the macro works fine on a single sheet, I am having difficulty looping my macro through every sheet, and am provided with an overflow error.

I am thinking that either the sheer sum of querying is unfit for Excel, or that I need to somehow redefine my outputs as long integers.

```
Sub Summation()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For X = 1 To WS_Count

    Sheets(X).Select

     Dim total As Variant

     Dim attribute As String
     Dim data_last_row As Variant
     Dim attribute_last_row As Variant

     Range("I1").Value = "Unique Attribute"
     Range("L1").Value = "Total"

     data_last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     For I = 2 To data_last_row
         attribute = ws.Cells(I, 1)
         total = Cells(I, 7) + total
         attribute_last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
         If Cells(I + 1, 1) <> attribute Then
             Cells(attribute _last_row + 1, 9) = attribute 
         End If
         Cells(attribute _last_row + 1, 12) = total        
     Next I

Next X

End Sub
```

I also tried `For Each ws In Worksheets` and defining my Cells as `ws`, but 
the outputs were way off in every subsequent sheet, replicating essentially the results of the macro on the first sheet.

Is there another way, or is Excel simply not suited to process this much data?

Comment: You are using `Dim ... As Integer` when you should be using `As Long`.  And you should declare *all* your variables

Comment: in `attribute = ws.Cells(I, 1)` you did not declare what `ws` is

Comment: The VBA Integer datatype has a limit of 32,767.  Any higher and you will get an Overflow error.  Use Long instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should kind of work now.

`attribute` should not be declared as a variable as it is a keyword

`attributes _last_row` had a space in the middle. Probably a typo but do take note.

```
Sub Summation()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For X = 1 To WS_Count

    Set ws = Sheets(X)

    Dim total As Variant


    Dim attributes As String
    Dim data_last_row As Variant
    Dim attributes_last_row As Variant

    ws.Range("I1").Value = "Unique Attribute"
    ws.Range("L1").Value = "Total"

    data_last_row = Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To data_last_row
        attributes = ws.Cells(I, 1)
        total = ws.Cells(I, 7) + total
        attributes_last_row = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(I + 1, 1) <> attributes Then
             ws.Cells(attributes_last_row + 1, 9) = attributes
        End If

        ws.Cells(attributes_last_row + 1, 12) = total

    Next I

Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was able to loop through all my sheets, however I have one persistent issue and that is: while my first sheets aggregates my values by my attributes, on the subsequent sheets 1) I generate outputs for each rows and 2) the values themselves are off, leading me to believe that the summing iteration of the first sheet leads into the second and so forth, while failing to execute the sum by attribute loop. I marked this question solved since my original question was a matter of being able to execute my macro through my workbook.